# Is there a package for segmenting a large TeX document so that the PDF can be downloaded in installment?

Tags: hyperref

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create individual chapter PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs)

Suppose a lengthy book, as a PDF file, is to be made available online to students. In order to avoid bandwidth problems it makes sense to cut the book in chapters and have students download front and end matter first and then download one chapter at a time.

The answers to ["Does Hyperref Work Between Two Files?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files/41547#41547/) indicates it is possible to do so with an in-house solution. I was wondering if there is a package that automates and standardizes  the process.

A side question:

An item seemingly missing from above solutions is the ability to open a link in a new PDF file, just as in a browser where you can open a link in a new window. This is useful for easy side-by-side comparison. Can this one be done?

An answer to the Side question:
Opening a link in a new PDF is a function of the (Adobe) Reader.
On Adobe go to Edit->Preferences->General un-check Enable Protected Mode (after reading the security risks) then multiple PDF's can co-exist.

Comment: check this post, I asked similar question. I created 6 volume book with 540 chapters. each chapter was converted to a smaller pdf. worked great http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs

Comment: Somewhat unrelated side-comment: it is sometimes useful to have access to the full pdf too, so the best may be to provide both the full pdf and the individual chapters.

Comment: @Aku: Note that linking to an answer does not qualify as a new answer. Please use comments for this. Thnaks.