# How do I create a book with separately produced chapters?

Tags: book-design

I want to create a book type file, where each chapter is separatly compiled. That is I get the whole thing as well as each individual chapters in pdf or dvi or ps format. How do I do that?

Comment: Compiling each chapter separately will produce a PDF file with the same "Chapter 1" heading, are you ok with this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I would suggest you have a look at the [the `standalone` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone). There are numerous examples on this site.

Comment: Probably the quickest method is to separate the chapters with a PDF utility such as `qpdf` or `pdftk`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs

Comment: It's not quite clear from your question *exactly* what you want to achieve with regard to page and chapter numbering. Have you looked at the functionality provided by `\include` and `\includeonly`, described, for example, on page 18 of The LaTeX Companion (2nd Edition)?

Answer (score 9):

Without using packages, you could use simply the \input commands:

Write each chapter in a separate file (don't compile these files):

In chapter1.tex:

```
intro to chapter 1
\section{section 1}
section 1 of chapter 1
\section{section 2}
section 2 of chapter 1
```

In chapter2.tex:

```
intro to chapter 2
\section{section 1}
section 1 of chapter 2
\section{section 2}
section 2 of chapter 2
```

Then write your book as:

in book.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\title{Title}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1 title}
\input{chapter1}

\chapter{Chapter 2 title}
\input{chapter2}

\end{document}
```

Compile this file to get your full book.

To get the separate chapter as articles, you can compile the following file:

In chapter1Article.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of chapter X}
\maketitle

\input{chapterX}

\end{document}
```

If you want them as a book with only one chapter, use the following file. To get the right chapter number, use \setcounter.

In chapter1Book.tex:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{X-1}

\chapter{title of chapter X}
\input{chapterX}

\end{document}
```

etc...

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to have each chapter in a separate file and then use the `\include` command to fold them all into a big main file. Then you can use `\includeonly` to compile each chapter individually. If you compile the whole thing first, then when you do `\includeonly` you'll get the right numbering and crossreferences would work.

To automate things, what you'd want is a script that does `\includeonly` for each chapter one after the other, and also changes the `jobname` such that each chapter is compiled to a distinct file.