# arara: toggle identifier in the rule

Tags: arara

I'm working on an [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) rule that makes use of the `items` identifier

```
% arara: myrule: {items: [lions, zebras]}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

hello world

\end{document}
```

The rule, `myrule.yaml`, looks like this:

```
!config
identifier: myrule
name: myrule
commands: 
- <arara> @{ isTrue( myswitch, isWindows( "cmd /c echo", "echo" ) ) } @{item}
# can I toggle myswitch here?
arguments:
- identifier: myswitch
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.myswitch}
  default: true
```

I would like to toggle the `myswitch` identifier to `false` within the rule- how can I do this? `:)`

<sub>(The reason is for the rule I made for [How to create individual chapter PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs)).</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, it's not possible to have a switch in the rule context.

When using iterators like `items/@{item}` or `files/@{file}`, the rule is replicated to every item; the context is stateless, it has no previous memory of past expansions.

One possible dirty hack is to compare the current `@{item}` to a variable supplied by the directive and execute one of the commands if and only if they are equal:

```
!config
identifier: myrule
name: myrule
commands: 
- <arara> @{ isTrue( item == element, isWindows( "cmd /c echo", "echo" ) ) } @{item}
arguments:
- identifier: element
  flag: <arara> @{parameters.element}
```

And in the directive:

```
% arara: myrule: { items: [ lions, zebras ], element: lions }
```

Note that `element` applies to the first item of the list.

With the upcoming version of `arara`, we might be able to perform checks in directives with something we call *conditionals*. We are still working on it, but so far, it looks good.

I'll think of adding a internal map containing some useful info to rulemakers, like the item count, the current item, and other goodies. Of course, it will be properly documented. `:)`