# arara: between silent and verbose mode

Tags: arara

Consider the following files

**`myfile.tex`**

```
% arara: myrule: {items: [lions, zebras]}
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

**`myrule.yaml`**

```
!config
#
# Sample usage
# % arara: myrule: {items: [lions]}
# % arara: myrule: {items: [lions, zebras]}
#
identifier: myrule
name: Myrule
commands: 
- <arara> echo @{item}
arguments: []
```

If I run [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) in `verbose` mode on `myfile.tex` using

```
arara -v myfile
```

then the output is

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running Myrule... 

lions
Status: SUCCESS

Running Myrule... 

zebras
Status: SUCCESS
```

If I run it in `silent` mode using

```
arara myfile
```

then the output is

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running Myrule... SUCCESS
Running Myrule... SUCCESS
```

I would like to get more information about the `@{item}` currently being processed, even when I'm compiling in `silent` mode; explicitly, my desired result (when running `arara myfile`) would be something like

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running Myrule (lions)... SUCCESS
Running Myrule (zebras)... SUCCESS
```

Is such output possible?

<sub>PS: My example above is a toy example- the 'real-life' code is in [How to create individual chapter PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs)</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now you make me feel really bad and regret my decision of not making the `name` field in the `arara` rule specification expandable. `:)`

I'm deeply sorry, but this is not possible. When I defined the rule spec, back in version `1.0`, I could not find out any real world example for providing variable expansion in the `name` field. As usual, time proved me wrong, and your example clearly presents a nice user case of how one could benefit from a feature like this. `:)`

That said, I think this feature is very doable and might reach the upcoming versions of `arara`. Sadly, `arara` is becoming more and more complex feature-wise, and I'm really worried of breaking backwards compatibility (I already did in `3.0`, and I'm not inclined to do it again), since now we have a larger user base. I have an alternative solution, which might be a fork under a new bird name, which holds the bleeding edge features for advanced users, while `arara` keeps the traditional approach without breaking compilation chains. Let's see what I'll be able to come up with, time will tell. `:)`

**Edit:** percusse suggested in the chatroom for us to create a third execution mode, which is the middle of `silent` and `verbose`, called `sibose`. Oh my. `:P`

Comment: Thanks Paulo! I certainly didn't mean to make you feel bad `:"(` I love the tool- this question was more of an idea than anything else `:)` Thanks for releasing such a wonderful tool!