# Reference non-included chapters in large document

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, chapters, include

I have a large document that contains many different chapters which reference each other. The body of the main latex file looks something like:

```
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
...
\include{chapter10}
```

I wish to create several documents that only contain selected chapters (i.e. chapters 3 and 8). These chapters should be numbered the same as they are in the main document so the nice latex auto-numbering is less than helpful in this case. I know I can use `\setcounterdepth` to make sure the chapters are numbered as I wish so that's not a problem. However, once I am no longer including a chapter, latex doesn't know where to point the reference to.

Is there any solution where the compiler looks at all of the files but only actually includes some in the compiled document?

I also want *only* the included chapters to be in the TOC. Not sure if that would complicate the problem at hand.

Comment: The first part of your question can easily be achieved by using, for example, 

     `\includeonly{lions,zerbras}`

Note that this assumes that the necessary `.aux` files are already in place. You can read further details in [How to create individual chapter PDFs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31334)

The part of your question related to the `toc` is quite tricky.