# Solution to 'Multiple PDF generation with one tex file' does not work anymore with TeXLive 2016

Tags: macros, luatex, shell-escape, texlive-2016

The solution in [Multiple PDF generation with one tex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162042/multiple-pdf-generation-with-one-tex-file) worked with TeXLive 2015 and is now broken in TeXLive 2016, at least on OS X El Capitan.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ifx\conditionmacro\undefined
\immediate\write18{%
  lualatex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape --jobname="\jobname"
  "\gdef\string\conditionmacro{1}\string\input\space\jobname"
}%
\expandafter\stop
\fi
\begin{document}
asdf
\end{document}
```

Result with TeXLive 2015:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `mini' with ``lualatex --jobname=mini  -file-line-error -shell-escape --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" mini.tex''
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 \write18 enabled.
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(./mini.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 \write18 enabled.
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(./mini.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
No file mini.aux.
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./mini.aux))
 264 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 40 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:12,3:3,4:22,6:11,7:1,9:6
<</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on mini.pdf (1 page, 10762 bytes).

SyncTeX written on mini.synctex.gz.Transcript written on mini.log.
)
 262 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 39 glue_spec, 2 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:12,3:1,6:3,9:1
No pages of output.
Transcript written on mini.log.

TeX Output finished at Mon Jun 13 14:32:07
```

Result in TeXLive 2016:

```
Running `LaTeX' on `mini' with ``lualatex --jobname=mini  -file-line-error -shell-escape --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\input" mini.tex''
This is LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016) 
 system commands enabled.
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 1 language(s) loaded.
(./mini.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
lualatex --synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape --jobname="mini" "\gdef \conditionmacro{1}\input mini" 
)
 347 words of node memory still in use:
2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 6 glue, 40 glue_spec, 2 write nodes
avail lists: 2:12,3:1,4:1,5:2,7:1,9:1

warning  (pdf backend): no pages of output.
Transcript written on mini.log.

TeX Output finished at Mon Jun 13 14:20:51
```

Any hints how one can get it running in TeXLive 2016?

Comment: As I look at the log: --shell-escape seems not to enable \write18 anymore

Comment: @AlexanderWilms better to say in order to use `\write18` you need that package (`--shell-escape`  still enables/disables `os.execute` as it did before)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\write18` no longer means execute system commands in luatex.

add

```
\usepackage{shellesc}
```

to re-enable it.

That package will also allow the clearer syntax

```
\ShellEscape{...}
```

instead of

```
\write18{...}
```

or since you are writing code specifically for luatex you could avoid using `shellesc` and use

```
\directlua{os.execute("\luaescapestring{...}")}
```

which would work in old or new luatex.

Comment: @Zoltán Please accept the answer, click on the hook. (Is it a »hook« in English?)

Comment: @KeksDose do you mean the \checkmark? ;)

Comment: @KeksDose I'd call it a 'tick'. I don't think Americans say that though.