# Speed up compilation of document with chemfig drawings

Tags: compiling, chemfig

I'm writing a document containing many chemical reactions drawn with `chemfig`.
As I build it up, the compilation time is increasing unexpectedly fast and has reached nearly 1 minute for about 50 pages. It's not that much for a single compilation, but it sums up.

So, is there a way to reduce it?
Maybe a way to "store" the reactions and reuse them in the following compilation, like the `svg` package that requires the `--shell-escape` option only if the document contains an image that has not been converted yet?

Comment: Maybe compiling only the section/chapter that you are currently working on would be a solution? See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277565/is-there-any-macro-to-generate-latex-pdf-without-a-chapter/277598 .

Comment: @Marijn Not exactly; I'd prefer to get the full document when I compile the source. However, it's still much better than nothing: the process is now about 60% faster!