# Warning message with fonts: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right

Tags: fonts, xetex, cross-referencing, fontspec, polyglossia

Why do XeLaTeX return this warning message:

> Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

when using some fonts as Amiri and how one can get out of this warning message. I need to fix this to run `arara` on my files.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[quiet,nolocalmarks]{polyglossia}  
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}         % with 'Times New Roman' one get no warning
\begin{document}
\chapter{الفصل الأول}
\chapter{الفصل الثاني}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what are your arara instructions, you haven't put them in your mwe.

Comment: the warning is normal, and usually goes if you do what it says and re-run latex. Do you mean that you get the warning even if you run xelatex multiple times?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: There is something fishy, the warning doesn't disappear. I'm just looking why.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In fontspec-xetex.sty some of the conditionals (e.g. `\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \fontspec_check_script:n {TF}` set `\@tempswatrue`. And as some of this code is executed when the aux is read, the label test fails for some fonts.

Comment: @ArTourter My arara instruction is 
% arara: makechapters: {items: [Chapter1, chapter2,...]}
and needs some modifications to my origianl code. It helps creating individual chapters. [Here is more information about this rule](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114968/22432)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that sounds like a bug, where's Will when we need him:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: It is certainly a bug, but I wonder a bit now about \if@tempswa. Is it a good idea that the kernel uses it to get the "label state"? It is used in many places, packages and classes and it looks like a small  wonder that it doesn't clash more often.

Comment: @Ulrike / David — I'll try remember to switch to an internal Boolean. Happy new year!!

Comment: @WillRobertson or as Ulrike says we could use a dedicated flag in the label test... (one for team list probably)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: In the long run that sounds like a good idea, but fontspec is probably easier and faster to change.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer normally yes but 2016/01/01 is apparently getting close...

Comment: Has now been fixed in the pre-release fontspec code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug report and meanwhile solved (see comments).