# How to split a PDF into chapters or sections?

Tags: table-of-contents, split

I'm searching for a way to split up a full PDF into single PDFs containing the single chapters of the document.

Usually I'm using `pdfjam` to split / merge / ... PDFs, is there a simple way to split up depending on the table of content?

Comment: Interesting question! Have a look at `pdfsam`, according to this comment https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs#comment61715_31334 it allows you split by hyperref bookmarks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [samcarters answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/466842/142761) I found a nice solution using [sejda](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda).
The command to split up a PDF depending on the 1st level of the table of content, created with hyperref using LaTeX reads

```
sejda-console splitbybookmarks --bookmarkLevel 1 --files <input.pdf> --output <output_directory>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting an answer! Please don't hesitate to change the accepted status to your answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Based on the comment [How to create individual chapter PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31334/how-to-create-individual-chapter-pdfs#comment61715_31334)

If you have a document that uses `hyperref`, e.g. this one

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap1}
\lipsum

\chapter{chap2}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

you can use [`pdfsam`](https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam) to split at a bookmark level of your choice using this option:

[image]

In the next step you can chose your file, the bookmark level and the output name and location

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! 
the [command line version of pdfsam](https://github.com/torakiki/sejda) works like a charm for my problem. 
cheers.

Comment: @madn Good to hear that your problem is solved! Can you write an additional answer about your solution using sejda? This could be very helpful for future users with the same problem as you.