# how to generate document statistics?

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, statistics

In [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24397/extract-document-statistics-how-many-pages-has-chapter-xy-count-fixmes), manual steps are explained to implement stats.

Due to a deadline and for some convenience, is there a package that generates document stats without many modifications in several chapters?

For instance, `tba -> actual count or value`

```
chapter 1 - pages tba
          - sections tba 
          - subsections tba
          - figures tba
chapter 2 - pages tba
.. and so on ..
..
..
pdflatex version - tba
bibtex version - tba
```

Comment: Maybe the package `totalcount` (part of the `caption` bundle) can help you: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption

Comment: Are there  any news here? Did package `totalcount` help you?